# Bamboo can't run/read Maven parameter with quotes or double quotes in command line

Tags: maven, cucumber, bamboo

I'm struggling with create Bamboo maven-related build to execute tests by tags in below example is a **cucumber.tags** variable:

locally everything work perfectly (*pom.xml* is configured correctly)
I can run test with command:

`mvn test -Dcucumber.tags="@five and @one"`

But problem will appears when I try run it on Bamboo :

[image]

Bamboo executor will fail because of `"` characters

Is there any workaaround for this?

Comment: Have you tried to use single quotes `'` instead of `"`

Comment: yes I tried also escape symbols like ```\x20```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem by:

`mvn test "-Dcucumber.tags=@five and @one"`

and  by add a **Requirement** to execute maven on **Windows machine** (shell is crucial)